# Use part of an environment variables path to add files in other directories

Tags: nsis

How can I extract a partial path from an environment variable at compile time to use with the `File` command

Lets say my environment variable is:

```
MY_ENV_VAR
```

Lets say its value is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Program Name\Stuff\New Stuff"
```

I want to include the following file in my script:

```
"C:\Program Files\Program Name\Other Stuff\myFile.txt"
```

Therefore I want to do:

```
StrCpy $0 "$%MY_ENV_VAR%" -16
File "$0\Other Stuff\myFile.txt"
```

The above code wont work as `$0` and `StrCpy` are unavailable at compile time.
How can I achieve my desired result?

I cannot hard code the path to myFile as the install directory is likely to change from user to user

The only solution I have found uses a secondary script to create a .nsh file with a define to the path.
This however is ugly and also requires the user compiling two different .nsi scripts.

Comment: Alternatively if there is a syntax I have missed from the 'File' reference that allows an up directory such as "../" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment.

You can add a file in this way:

```
File "$%MY_ENV_VAR%\..\..\Other Stuff\myFile.txt"
```